# Xcode 9.1 Warns "Language directional layout margins before iOS 11.0"

Tags: ios, swift, margin, ios-autolayout

I noticed an Xcode warning that said :

> "Language directional layout margins before iOS 11.0"

Even this question left unanswered in [Apple developer forum thead.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84431)

I have used storyboard & warning doesn't lead to any specific view.

What is the cause or any solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am able to figure out the cause for the warning.

In `Storyboard -> Size Inspector`, set `Layout Margin` to `Default`. Which was `Language Directional` before.

[image: Size_inspectory_screenshot]

As per documentation, for the root view of a view controller, `UIKit` enforces a set of minimum layout margins to ensure that content is displayed correctly. When the values in the *`Language Directional` property are less than the minimum values, `UIKit` uses the minimum values instead*.